# Using pika, is it possible to read rabbitmq binding arguments?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

Look at the following screenshot

[image]

My queue has a binding with an exchange named `foo` only receiving messages with Routing key `bar`. I have also defined a pair of arguments `{baz: qux}`. Now I have a following code:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(...)
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(...)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='this_queue')
```

And the callback has the following signature:

```
def callback(channel, method, properties, body):
    ....
```

Now the question: how do I access arguments (`{baz: qux}`) inside the callback. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as AMQP doesn't provide that information in the response to `basic.consume`. You can use the [HTTP API](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.8/priv/www/api/index.html) to retrieve that information as long as you have the `rabbitmq_management` plugin enabled (which you must, if you took that screen shot).

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) library [amqpstorm](https://pypi.org/project/AMQPStorm/) to get this type of information.

```
from amqpstorm.management import ManagementApi

API = ManagementApi('http://127.0.0.1:15672', 'guest', 'guest')
print(API.queue.bindings('simple_queue', virtual_host='/'))
```

The result would look something like this.

```
[
    {
        "source": "",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "simple_queue",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "simple_queue",
        "arguments": {},
        "properties_key": "simple_queue"
    },
    {
        "source": "amq.direct",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "simple_queue",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "test",
        "arguments": {},
        "properties_key": "test"
    }
]
```

More examples available [here](https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/tree/master/examples/management_api).